# R data.table j is valid only when there is no by when performing a join

Tags: r, data.table

I'll just dive right into it...

```
DT_1 <- data.table(pk = c(1,1,2,2), val = 1:4, key = 'pk')
DT_2 <- data.table(pk = 1:2, att = c('a','b'), key = 'pk')
```

This works.

```
> DT_2[i = DT_1, j = `:=`(max_val = max(val))]
> DT_2
   pk att max_val
1:  1   a       4
2:  2   b       4
```

This doesn't.

```
> DT_2[i = DT_1, j = `:=`(max_val = max(val)), by = .(pk)]
Error in `[.data.table`(DT_2, i = DT_1, j = .(max(val)), by = .(pk)) : 
  object 'val' not found
```

Why and what do I do about it?

Comment: What would you like to accomplish? Please give a sample output!

Comment: `by=.EACHI` is the only supported aggregation during a join, as far as I know. You could do `DT_2[DT_1][, max(val), by=pk]`, though it's not ideal. This is maybe related: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/733

Comment: Thanks for linking that up @Frank. I raised that FR's priority.

Comment: Thanks for the `by=.EACHI` tip @Frank. That happens to address my use case, but I don't think it's too hard to create example where is doesn't.

Comment: this Q is asking for same feature as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746882/join-inherited-scope-with-by-in-data-table but here it asks for `:=`, so not marking as duplicate